# Saving a search string to use in other cshtml pages in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to save input (an address) from an html form in order to use in other cshtml pages in my asp.net core web application. I am also using Razor as a template language. I have a web application in which the user will enter an address on one page and then on another page I want to use that input and place it into an api call. My html form is below.

```
    <form method="post" action="/Features">
        <p>
            Address: <input type="text" name="searchString"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

I have previously used sessions but it was for an asp.net project using web forms (I believe) and am not sure if this is the route I should go. The address being entered doesn't need to be kept secure. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use session, ViewBag, TempData but using view model is more clean

Comment: If you're returning a view from your post request then a simple model/ViewBag/ViewData would do the job but if you're redirecting to another page then using `TempData` is the best option.

Comment: So I am kind of new to Razor pages. I am using Razor pages PageModel classes, which I have read are actually the View Models also. How would I use the view model to save this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Submit the form to your page, store the address in `TempData` then redirect to the second page where you would use your submitted value (Here you use the `Post/Redirect/Get` pattern in order to avoid your form being submitted again by mistake via a page reload).
2. Submit the form directly to the second page.

Going with the first option is recommended.

Page:

```html
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Features">
    <p>
        Address: <input type="text" name="searchString"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Handler:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostFeatures(string searchString)
{
    TempData["Key"] = searchString;
    return RedirectToPage("/SecondPage");
}
```

Then on your second page you get the `searchString` in the same way via:

```cs
string value = TempData["Key"] as string;
```

As i said you can also submit your form to the second page where you can do what ever you want with your value. Just be careful of multiple submissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to use TempData in Razor page:

cshtml:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Features">
        <p>
            Address: <input type="text" name="searchString"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostFeatures(string searchString) {
                TempData["searchString"] = searchString;
                xxxxxxx
            }
```

Other Page you want to use searchString:

```
string searchString=TempData["searchString"];
//TempData.Keep(); can help you keep the value,and you can still use the searchString value in other place
TempData.Keep();
```

or you can use

```
string searchString=TempData.Peek("searchString");
```

So that you can still keep the searchString value